# keycloak - realm resolution based on username (email address)

Tags: single-sign-on, multi-tenant, keycloak

I'm working on a multi tenant project where usernames are actually their email addresses and the domain of the email serves as a tenant identifier.

Now in keycloak I'll have different realms per tenant, but I want to have a single login page for all tenants and the actual realm that will do the authentication to be somehow resolved by the username (email address).

How do I go about doing that?

I found a thread on the mailing list (that I cant find now...) that discussed the same problem. It was something along the lines of - create a main realm that will "proxy" to the others, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a single authentication flow shared by all realms?

Comment: @RémiBantos I think so? something like have `proxy` realm, when user@corp.com logs in - somehow determine that the actual realm is `corp.com` and authenticate there.

Comment: If this is a multi-tenant app with really a lot of realms, Keycloak may have some scalability issues with that: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The idea](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-November/012406.html) from the mailing list is to write a service (let's say `auth-redirector.example.com`) that has a single input field for email, finds realm based on domain and redirects to that realm's keycloak endpoint (e.g. `auth.example.com/auth/realms/realm-name/etc…`) while keeping all GET params.

You can find examples of direct login/registration URLs here: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-July/007045.html

One usability problem is that users would have to provide their email twice, I have not yet found a way to pass the username via the login URL.

Comment: Found a way to preload the username: `login_hint` GET param from oidc spec.

Comment: This doesn't work with Single-Sign-On: If the user is already logged in to another application we don't want to show any dialog at all. The user should (appear to) be logged in completely automatically.

Comment: I guess that the "email input" service could check if the user is already logged in.

Comment: I think you're right, actually. Sorry. I've elaborated in my own answer below.

Comment: Either the email-input service can check (or) make the email-input service one of the subdomains of all your apps, such that if the browser has cookies, you can take them directly to the app instead of the "email-input" service. I have already implemented this functionality at my company, which is working perfectly fine. Contact me, and I can help you design if needed.

Answer (score 7):

I think Michał Łazowik's answer is on the right track, but for Single-Sign-On to work, it needs to be extended a little.

Keep in mind that because of [KEYCLOAK-4593](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-4593) if we have > 100 realms we may have to have multiple Keycloak servers also.

We'll need:

- A separate HTTP server specifically for this purpose, `auth-redirector.example.com`.
- An algorithm to determine the Keycloak server and realm from a username (email address).

Here would be the entire OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow:

An application discovers the user wants to log in. Before multiple realms, the realm's name would be a constant, so the application would redirect to:

`https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/realname/protocol/openid-connect/auth?$get_params`

Instead, it redirects to

`https://auth-redirector.example.com/?$get_params`

auth-redirector determines if it itself has a valid access token for this session, perhaps having to refresh the access token first from the Keycloak server that issued it (the user could have logged out and is trying to login as a different user that is served by a different realm).

If it *has* an valid access token we can determine the Keycloak server and realm from the username or email address in the access token and redirect to:

`https://$keycloak_server/auth/$realm/realname/protocol/openid-connect/auth?$get_params`

from here, the OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow proceeds as usual.

Else if it *doesn't* have a a valid access token, the auth-redirector stores the original app's `$get_params` as session data. It presents a form to the user asking for a username. When the user submits that, we can determine the Keycloak server and realm to use and then auth-redirector *itself* logs in to the Keycloak server using its own `$get_params`. Once the auth-redirector gets a call-back, it retrieves the access+refresh token from the Keycloak server and stores them in session data. It then, finally, redirects back to that same keycloak server and realm with the callers original `$get_params` (from session data). And the OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow proceeds as usual.

This is definitely a hack! But I think it could work. I'd love to try it out some day, time permitting.

Other hacks/solutions are needed for other OAuth2 flows...

Comment: This now has 7 upvotes. Has anybody actually tried it? I haven't and likely won't as I've since changed jobs.