# One realm per organization

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to figure out how to model my app.

In the app, users belong to organizations and each org can have multiple users. Also, each org can have their own password policies for it's users, decided by the org admin

What would be a good way to model this in Keycloak?

Thought about creating a new realm via the REST every api time a new org account is created. Each realm maps to an organization.

My client (web app) will have to be shared between the realms.

Does this kind of use case documented anywhere ?

Thanks

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583833/keycloak-realm-resolution-based-on-username-email-address

Comment: If you've got different web app instances per realm, go with a realm-different config. If everything is in the same app and you need to share info between different organizations, I would rather go with a single realm.

Comment: @XtremeBiker how would you do single realm but still have different password policies for each org ?

Comment: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-October/003351.html

Comment: Thanks. But it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I only have one client - SPA in Angular. I don't think this is the use case

Comment: If this is a multi-tenant app with really a lot of realms, Keycloak may have some scalability issues with that: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4593